Hyper-V hosted 6.9 Centos sshd and httpd services stopped at the same time 2 Saturdays in a row
It happened on August 3 and July 27 both times at 1:00 am. Here are the httpd logs.
[Sat Aug 03 01:00:01 2024] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Sat Jul 27 01:00:01 2024] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Here are the secure logs.
Aug  3 01:00:01 picco2 sshd[1745]: Received signal 15; terminating.

Jul 27 01:00:01 picco2 sshd[1775]: Received signal 15; terminating.

Here are the messages logs. This occurred at the same time both services shut down.
Aug  3 01:00:01 picco2 acpid: exiting
Aug  3 01:00:01 picco2 abrtd: Got signal 15, exiting

Jul 27 01:00:01 picco2 acpid: exiting
Jul 27 01:00:01 picco2 rpc.statd[1414]: Caught signal 15, un-registering and exiting
Jul 27 01:00:02 picco2 rpcbind: rpcbind terminating on signal. Restart with "rpcbind -w"

The system was not shutdown after receiving these messages. The problem was only found after trying to ssh into the server at 8am.
I am not sure what to try. I don't know the cause of the issue. I even checked event logs on the Windows Server 2022 Hyper-V host and did not find anything occurring at the same time. The CentOS VM has a static IP. The Hyper-V host receives its IP from DHCP. I created a bash script to check if sshd is running and if not it starts it. I know CentOS has been EOL for almost 4 years. I just want to find the root cause before I have to upgrade CentOS.

Really need to find what is sending the kill.   Do you have stap (systemtap) installed?  If so you can set a probe for signal 15 being sent to sshd.
